# Navigate On Image Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm trying to display a book review when someone clicks on any of the book images (onClick function) which should take them to the book review page of that particular book in a new route. I loaded the book covers manually in Books.js and then displayed the individual book cover in Book.js.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: See Image]

Books.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import atomicHabits from "../../../assets/images/books/atomicHabits.jpg";
import fourhourworkweek from "../../../assets/images/books/4-hour-work-week.jpg";
import almanack from "../../../assets/images/books/alamanack-naval.jpg";
import richDadPoorDad from "../../../assets/images/books/richDadPoorDad.jpg";
import lawsOfPower from "../../../assets/images/books/48LawsOfPower.jpg";
import showYourWork from "../../../assets/images/books/showYourWork.jpg";
import Book from "./Book";

const Books = () => {
  const books = [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "The 4-Hour Work Week",
      description: "ABCD",
      img: lawsOfPower,
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
      description: "EFGH",
      img: richDadPoorDad,
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: "Show Your Work",
      description: "IJKL",
      img: showYourWork,
    },
    {
      _id: 4,
      name: "Atomic Habits",
      description: "IJKL",
      img: atomicHabits,
    },
    {
      _id: 5,
      name: "The Almanack of Naval Ravikant",
      description: "IJKL",
      img: almanack,
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      name: "The 4-Hour Work Week",
      description: "IJKL",
      img: fourhourworkweek,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div id="bookshelf">
      <div className="font-bold text-3xl mt-24 mb-8">
        <h3>My Bookshelf</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-10 ">
        {books.map((book) => (
          <Book key={book._id} book={book}></Book>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Books;
```

Book.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Book.css";

const Book = ({ book }) => {
  const { _id, name, img, description } = book;
  return (
    <div className="card book-container card-compact w-56 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
      <figure>
        <img className="h-full w-full" src={img} alt="Books" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Book;
```

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: ah forgot to mention that. Yes I am using react router

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react router, you can use [useNavigate hook](https://beta.reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)  for e.g

```
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // declared at the top level


  <figure onClick={()=> navigate(`/book-review-route/{id}`)}>
    <img className="h-full w-full" src={img} alt="Books" />
  </figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either issue a declarative navigation with the [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Book.css";

const Book = ({ book }) => {
  const { _id, name, img, description } = book;
  return (
    <div className="card book-container card-compact w-56 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
      <figure>
        <Link to={`/book/${_id}`}>
          <img className="h-full w-full" src={img} alt="Books" />
        </Link>
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or issue an imperative navigation with the `navigate` function via the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook and an attached click handler:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Book.css";

const Book = ({ book }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { _id, name, img, description } = book;
  return (
    <div className="card book-container card-compact w-56 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
      <figure>
        <img
          className="h-full w-full"
          src={img}
          alt="Books"
          role="link"
          onClick={() => navigate(`/book/${_id}`)}
        />
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Using the `Link` is the more HTML semantically correct and accessible way to link to another page, if you use an `onClick` handler then you'll want to specify any additional accessibility attributes to ensure your app is accessible to screen readers and other accessibility tools.

Comment: I thought I could use this only if all my book reviews were in one single json file in an array. However, I want to import each component conditionally. For example, if someone clicks on the Atomic Habits image, the user will see the content of the component <AtomicHabits></AtomicHabits> and the same goes for the other books. Is this plausible to be achieved using the above method?

Comment: @SpeedBird Plausible, yes, I suppose it is if you're declaring a React component for each book you are rendering, the routed content can be a dynamic type computed at runtime. This IMO tends towards unmaintainability. It would be similar to how you've imported an image for each book entry, as the number of books grows so does the number of imports. It's *technically* maintainable, but just incredibly messy. The more practical and conventional method is to have a single dynamic component that simply receives the book data and renders each the same way.

Comment: hmm, that's a more likable idea. I have one question though: if passing all the book reviews from a single component, can I style them differently? For example, for one book I may just write one paragraph and for another it could be split in different paragraphs/columns. How do I then achieve this?

Comment: @SpeedBird That sounds like a content issue more than it is a styling issue. How I've solved this in the past is either storing an array of paragraphs (*to be mapped*) or treat the content as a whole a single entity and use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), which is safe if you control the content. If you ***do not*** control the content then you'll want to sanitize the content prior to rendering it. Does this make sense?

Comment: I see. Sorry for the late response as I was a bit away from work. So I have decided to store the reviews in a JSON file and fetch it from there. Currently facing an issue with fetching the data. Could you kindly have a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167659/cant-display-json-data-using-useparams?noredirect=1#comment130947866_74167659