# Can't display JSON data using useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, parameter-passing

I've stored some book data in a JSON file and want to dynamically display the book reviews ('blog' in the json file) whenever someone clicks on a particular book cover. However the data is not being displayed on the UI and the console gives me `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

[image]

Can someone kindly guide me on what I'm doing wrong here?

`blogs.json` file:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The 48 Laws Of Power",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/RpP2LGp/48-Laws-Of-Power.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem seel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/8Brh2Nc/rich-Dad-Poor-Dad.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Show Your Work",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/VjLBT1T/show-Your-Work.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Atomic Habits",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto tiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/ss0kLQw/atomic-Habits.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "The Almanack Of Naval Ravikant",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/87SmcFz/alamanack-naval.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "The 4-Hour Work Week",
    "blog": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa qrelit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur",
    "img": "https://i.ibb.co/Pxtt4dH/4-hour-work-week.jpg"
  }
]
```

`Books.js` file:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Book from "./Book";

const Books = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("blogs.json")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setBooks(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="bookshelf">
      <div className="font-bold text-3xl mt-24 mb-8">
        <h3>My Bookshelf</h3>
      </div>

      <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-10 ">
        {books.map((book) => (
          <Book key={book.id} book={book}></Book>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Books;
```

`Book.js` file:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Book.css";

const Book = ({ book }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToBookReview = (id) => {
    navigate(`/book/${id}`);
  };

  const { id, name, img, description } = book;
  return (
    <div className="card book-container card-compact w-56 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
      <figure onClick={() => navigateToBookReview(id)}>
        <img className="h-full w-full" src={img} alt="Books" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Book;
```

`BookDetails.js` file:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const BookDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/book/${id}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setBlog(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is book details: {id} </h2>
      <h2>{blog.name}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookDetails;
```

`App.js` file:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Pages/Home/Shared/Navbar";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import NotFound404 from "./Pages/Home/Shared/NotFound404";
import BookDetails from "./Pages/Home/Books/BookDetails";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>} />
        <Route path="/book/:id" element={<BookDetails></BookDetails>} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound404></NotFound404>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How do you serve this json?

Comment: This means that the JSON resource you requested does not exist or is not being routed correctly. You're trying to parse HTML which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: As the others have said before, you're fetching from `http:localhost:3000/blogs.json` if you're running in development. You need to make sure that is available. Try `./books.json` if it is in the public directory.

Comment: @OFRBG could you elaborate a bit more please? So in BookDetails, I need to change the URL from `http://localhost:3000/book/${id}` to `http://localhost:3000/blogs.json/${id}`?  If I try that, I'm still unable to display the data on the UI

Comment: Where exactly is this `"blogs.json"` file located? If using the `fetch` call to pull it in it needs to be in the public directory and a directory structure that matches the current route. If it's a static file in the `/src` directory then it should just be imported locally. Please let us know where the `'blogs.json"` file it located.

Comment: @DrewReese it is indeed in the Public directory ( `public > blogs.json`)

Comment: Where is this `Books` component being rendered, i.e. the route/path for it, and where is the `blogs.json` file located in the public directory, just sitting in the root?

Comment: @DrewReese `Books` component is in the src path (`src > Pages > Home > Books > Books.js`). And the `blogs.json` is in the public folder so yes sitting in the root.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, in the code, the routed component rendering it. I'm really asking what the URL path is for the component rendering `Books`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `blogs.json` file is in the root `"/"` public directory then the `Books` component should use an absolute file path for it when fetching, otherwise the app will incorrectly use the current URL when requesting the resource, thinking it is a relative path. The resource should be `"/blogs.json"`.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/blogs.json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setBooks(data));
}, []);
```